# Date of achievement of Tiers

Tags: sql, mysql

I am working on a query in which I need to calculate the date of achievement of particular Tiers based on completion of courses on particular salesforce account.

There are 3 different tiers:

1. **Authorisation** - completion of any one of the courses
2. **Ascent** - (Sales 101 >= 3 AND sales 201 >= 2 AND tech 101 >= 1)
3. **Summit** - (Sales 101 >= 4 AND sales 201 >= 2 AND tech 101 >= 4 AND tech 201 >= 2)

My Input sample data looks like below:

| salesforce_account_id | acquired_date | sales 101 | sales 201 | tech 101 | tech 201 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| axyz | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| axyz | 2021-02-02 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| axyz | 2021-07-07 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| axyz | 2022-03-13 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| axyz | 2022-09-05 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| axyz | 2022-12-09 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Desired output:

| Salesforce_account_id | Authorized | Ascent | Summit | max_level_achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| axyz | 2021-01-01 | 2022-12-09 | null | Ascent |

Here 1 represent completion of course by an individual users. Each account has multiple users.

The max_level_achieved is based on if summit date is not null then it is having value as summit else if ascent date is not null then ascent else Authorisation.

My current query looks like this:

```
WITH TierCTE AS (
    SELECT
        Salesforce_account_id,
        MIN(acquired_date) AS Authorized,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Sales_101 >= 3 AND Sales_201 >= 2 AND Tech_101 >= 1 THEN acquired_date END) AS Ascent,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Sales_101 >= 4 AND Sales_201 >= 2 AND Tech_101 >= 4 AND Tech_201 >= 2 THEN acquired_date END) AS Summit,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Salesforce_account_id ORDER BY
                    CASE
                        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Sales_101 >= 4 AND Sales_201 >= 2 AND Tech_101 >= 4 AND Tech_201 >= 2 THEN acquired_date END) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Sales_101 >= 3 AND Sales_201 >= 2 AND Tech_101 >= 1 THEN acquired_date END) IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                        ELSE 3
                    END
                ) AS RowNum
    FROM YourTableName
    GROUP BY Salesforce_account_id
)
SELECT
    Salesforce_account_id,
    Authorized,
    Ascent,
    Summit,
    CASE
        WHEN Summit IS NOT NULL THEN 'Summit'
        WHEN Ascent IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ascent'
        ELSE 'Authorisation'
    END AS max_level_achieved
FROM TierCTE
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Output:

| Salesforce_account_id | Authorized | Ascent | Summit | max_level_achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| axyz | 2021-01-01 | null | null | Authorisation |

This query is not working correctly. The authorization date is working fine but for Ascent & Summit date it is giving null values even though it is reached to that tiers in some cases. Can you please help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Apologies for incomplete question.I am getting the authorized date correctly but ascent & summit date is not working. It is giving null . Even though it is already reached in ascent & summit in many cases. There is some issues in the count of the courses

Comment: Looks like you need to sum values at first, then make analysis: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0A9NWoFw).

Answer (score 0):

I am reluctant to post this as an answer, as it is mostly PonderStibbons's solution, but with the windows specified once in each CTE:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        Salesforce_account_id AS id,
        acquired_date         AS dt,
        SUM(sales_101) OVER w AS s1,
        SUM(sales_201) OVER w AS s2,
        SUM(tech_101)  OVER w AS t1,
        SUM(tech_201)  OVER w AS t2,
        ROW_NUMBER()   OVER w AS rn
    FROM YourTableName
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Salesforce_account_id ORDER BY acquired_date)
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT id, dt,
        MIN(CASE WHEN s1 >= 3 AND s2 >= 2 AND t1 >= 1             THEN dt END) OVER w AS Ascent,
        MIN(CASE WHEN s1 >= 4 AND s2 >= 2 AND t1 >= 4 AND t2 >= 2 THEN dt END) OVER w AS Summit,  
        rn
    FROM cte1
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id)
)
SELECT id, dt AS Authorized, Ascent, Summit, 
    CASE
        WHEN Summit IS NOT NULL THEN 'Summit'
        WHEN Ascent IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ascent'
        ELSE 'Authorisation'
    END AS max_level_achieved 
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C9T355uQ) shows the difference in overhead, just by reusing the window. It's not a huge saving, but ...